# how to connect to mssql using php mssql()

Tags: php, sql-server

there is a sample code below to connect to mysql

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=register', 'root', '12345');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into registered(name, email, password) values (?,?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $email);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $pwd);

$name = $_POST["fname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

$stmt->execute();
echo "<p>Thank you for registering!</p>";
?>
```

but i need a similar code like in the above to connect to "**mssql**" database using **mssql()** function for examle refer http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
in the above link there they connect to mysql without pdo

Comment: I'm confused. mssql and mysql are two entirely different things, which are you talking about here? The linked page seems to talk only about mysql.

Comment: yes it talks about mysql only but similar to the method in the code in that page i want to connect to mssql mr.Joachim Isaksson